# Create new array from existing array with unique joined values from existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anyone know how I can create a new array from existing array with unique joined values from existing array?

```
const originalArray = [
  [
    { value: 'red', id: 99 },
    { value: 'blue', id: 100 },
  ],
  [
    { value: 'small', id: 101 },
    { value: 'medium', id: 102 },
  ],
  [
    { value: 'modern', id: 103 },
    { value: 'classic', id: 104 },
  ],
];
//
//
const newArrayBasedOnOriginalArray = [
  { value: 'red/small/modern' },
  { value: 'red/small/classic' },
  { value: 'red/medium/modern' },
  { value: 'red/medium/classic' },
  { value: 'blue/small/modern' },
  { value: 'blue/small/classic' },
  { value: 'blue/medium/modern' },
  { value: 'blue/medium/classic' },
];
```

I calculated that the length of the new array should always be as following:

```
// length of new array
const lengthOfNewArray = originalArray
  .map((value) => {
    return value.length;
  })
  .reduce((current, old) => {
    return current * old;
  });
//
//
console.log('length of new array:', lengthOfNewArray); // 8
```

Comment: You can also have a look at this module I made a bunch of years ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/combinatorial-explosion

Answer (score 3):

You can do it recursively

```js
const originalArray = [
  [
    { value: 'red', id: 99 },
    { value: 'blue', id: 100 },
  ],
  [
    { value: 'small', id: 101 },
    { value: 'medium', id: 102 },
  ],
  [
    { value: 'modern', id: 103 },
    { value: 'classic', id: 104 },
  ],
];

const getPossibleCombination = (currentValue, arraysRemaining) => {
  if(arraysRemaining.length === 0) return currentValue

  const values = []
  
  const firstArray = arraysRemaining[0]
  
  firstArray.forEach(({value}) => {
    values.push(getPossibleCombination(`${currentValue}/${value}`, arraysRemaining.slice(1, arraysRemaining.length)))
  })
  
  return values.flat()
}

const values = getPossibleCombination('', originalArray)
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you do not necessarily need recursion. `Array.reduce()` greatly does the job:

```js
const originalArray = [
  [
    { value: 'red', id: 99 },
    { value: 'blue', id: 100 },
  ],
  [
    { value: 'small', id: 101 },
    { value: 'medium', id: 102 },
  ],
  [
    { value: 'modern', id: 103 },
    { value: 'classic', id: 104 },
  ],
];

const newArray = originalArray
  .map(elem => elem.map(({value}) => value))
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc.flatMap(seq => cur.map(part => `${seq}/${part}`)))
  .map(elem => ({value: elem}))

console.log(newArray)
```

Aside from the initial and final `map()`, used to simplify the input objects, what I am doing is continuously combining the accumulator with the next sub-array.

For each object in the sub-array I duplicate every object in the accumulator, using the nested `map()`. `flatMap()` is used to keep the accumulator flat, with a simple `map()` the accumulator depth would increase every time we visit a new sub-array.

Comment: Your example works really good. 

However, I tried to make an if statement, if value already exist, then do not return or overwrite the existing value.  

```
newArray = [{ value: 'red/small/modern', id: 1, price: 888 }];

```

So, value "red/small/modern" already exist with price 888, I do not want to overwrite this value and the price.

Could you help, to insert somekind of if statement  for existing values?

Comment: Glad you find it useful, please update the question with the new requirement. Don't forget to put the example and the expected result, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all if values in each of your arrays is unique then the concatenated values will be unique as well. After you make sure values are unique you can use this code to create combinations of strings:

```
const newArrayBasedOnOriginalArray = originalArray.reduce(
  (acc, el) =>
    el.flatMap(({ value }) =>
      acc.length ? acc.map((str) => str + "/" + value) : value
    ),
  []
).map(value=>({value});
```